# Avoid space between DOM when using pseudo class :before

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, stylesheet

I must be doing some basic thing wrong since I don't want the space between each letters below.

**HTML:**

```
<i class="icon icon1"></i>
<i class="icon icon2"></i>
<i class="icon icon3"></i>
```

**CSS:**

```
.icon {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    padding: 3px;
    background: yellow;
    margin: 0;
}

.icon1:before {
    content: "A";
}

.icon2:before {
    content: "B";
}

.icon3:before {
    content: "C";
}
```

**Link:** http://jsfiddle.net/qhoc/rkRBY/

I believe the space is automatically there between each character unless `font-size:0`. My requirements are:

- All chars must be on same line
- There will be more icon4, icon5, etc..
- No space between them without changing font-size
- OK to add HTML wrapper but would not touch JS or changing `<i>` to something else. I am using **Bootstrap** by the way.

Let me know if there is workaround! Thanks.

Comment: Do you want like this? [link](http://jsfiddle.net/rkRBY/1/).

Comment: `:before` is a pseudo-element, *not* a pseudo-class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two good ways afaik,

- Don't give space in HTML markup between the elements (or)
- add `display: table-cell` to that element.

Try this:

```
.icon {
    display: table-cell;
    /* removed padding: 3px; */
    position: relative;
    background: yellow;
    margin: 0px;
}

.icon1:before {
    content: "A";
}

.icon2:before {
    content: "B";
}

.icon3:before {
    content: "C";
}
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rkRBY/11/)

Comment: If you have many `i` then I suggest you to go with removing space in HTML because using `display: table-cell` keeps the elements in same line.

Comment: How does `display: table-cell` work differently from `display: inline-block` in term of creating space here? Just curious?!

Comment: @HP. Even I don't know that.. just realized in designing a website :)

Answer (score 1):

There is space between the elements so that,

```
<i class="icon icon1"></i><i class="icon icon2"></i><i class="icon icon3"></i>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rkRBY/10/

Comment: Good point. I didn't know linebreak can make a big deal. But I wrote HTML in Haml and it automatically created a new line for each DOM. Urgh!! So in a way, I can't use this.